# Multiple integral with max function

Tags: integration

> $$\idotsint_V \max \{u_1,u_2,...,u_n\} \,du_1 \dots du_n$$

where $V=[0,1]^n$.
I don't know how to begin.

Comment: Maybe try the case $n=2$ first, to see how it works? (Split into two subdomains along the diagonal $u_1=u_2$.)

Answer (score 1):

Put
\begin{equation*}
V_{i}=\{u\in V\, :\, u_{i} \ge \max(u_{1},\ldots ,u_{i-1},u_{i+1},\ldots ,u_{n}\}, \quad i = 1,2,\ldots, n.
\end{equation*}
Then $V = \cup_{i=1}^{n}V_{i}$ 
and $\cap_{i=1}^{n}V_{i}$ is a null set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
Consequently
\begin{gather*}
\int_{V}\max(u_{1},u_{2},\ldots ,u_{n})\, du_{1}\ldots du_{n} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{V_{i}}u_{i}\, du_{1}\ldots du_{n} =[\text{ symmetry }]=\\[2ex]
n\int_{V_{n}}u_{n}\, du_{1}\ldots du_{n} =n\int_{0}^{1}u_{n}\left(\int_{\max(u_{1},\ldots ,u_{n-1})\le u_{n}}1\, du_{1}\ldots du_{n-1}\right)\, du_{n}=\\[2ex]
n\int_{0}^{1}u_{n}\cdot u_{n}^{n-1}\, du_{n} = \dfrac{n}{n+1}.
\end{gather*}

Comment: Dear JanG, do you know of a reference for your solution and for similar problems?

Comment: $@$Sela I am sorry to say but I did not use any references.